# How do I retrieve Font name on c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I have richtextbox1. When I paste text into that I need to :

1. Get the exact font name what I have pasted into that richtextbox1 (Is there any method to retrive complete font detail of that?)
2. What is the suitable variable type to assign font detail (Is that **Font**?)

Please give me the easier suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.font.aspx

Comment: If the text you are pasting is rich text, you might have multiple fonts in the selection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SelectionFont` property to retrieve the font of the text you want. However, if the text you pasted uses multiple fonts, the property will return `null`.

As a test, I copy pasted some text from Word using three different fonts into the RichTextBox.

> "Font: [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8,25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]
>
> SelectionFont: [Font: Name=Cambria, Size=11, Units=3, GdiCharSet=0, GdiVerticalFont=False]"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `RichTextBox` control has a `Font` property, of type `Font`, which "Gets or sets the font used when displaying text in the control." And yes, `Font` is the right data structure for holding font information in .NET.

Comment: `RichTextBox` can have multiple fonts throughout the text. Are you sure `Font` is correct?

Comment: @Stijn Yes, but that is to do with the `SelectionFont` property, which is generally user-controlled by means of selecting from the font dialog and relates only to text currently selected.

Comment: -1 I've tested this, and `Font` simply outputs the default font instead of the font of the text you want.